# Rendering a specific javascript object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

```
{
    questionText: 'What is 4 + 5?',
    answerOptions: [
        { answerText: '14', isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: '9', isCorrect: true },
        { answerText: '11', isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: '20', isCorrect: false },
    ],
},
```

I have this javascript object. How can I render the correct option, in this case "9"?

```
{
  questions.map((answerOption) =>
    answerOption.answerOptions.isCorrect ? (
      <div>{answerOption.answerOptions.answerText}</div>
    ) : null,
  );
}
```

I tried this, but it's not giving me any output.

Comment: Is `questions` an array that has multiple objects like the one shown? Without more details people are left to guess at what it is exactly you are working with. Please take a few minutes to read through [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't write it, I guess your object is called `questions`.

If in the array you have a single object (like in the example you posted) you have to do something like this:

```
{
  questions.answerOptions.map((answerOption) => 
     answerOption.isCorrect ? <div>{answerOption.answerText}</div> : null)
}
```

Otherwise, if you have more than one object inside the array, you can put two `map` one inside the other:

```
{
  questions.map((answerOption) => 
      answerOption.answerOptions.map(el =>
         el.isCorrect ? <div>{el.answerText}</div> : null)
      )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after something like this:

```
{questions.answerOptions.filter(option=>option.isCorrect).map(answer=><div>answer.answerText</div>)}
```

Comment: I upvoted this because it does technically show the correct answer. But it is a very cumbersome way of doing it. I think we can leave the filter out and just do something like: 

`{questions.answerOptions.map(answer=> answer.isCorrect ? <div>answer.answerText</div> : null)}`

Answer (score 0):

Your `answerOptions` is an array, so you will need to iterate over that as well. You can use the `Array#find()` method to find the element where `isCorrect` is `true`:

```js
function App() {
  let questions = [
    {
      questionText: 'What is 4 + 5?',
      answerOptions: [
        { answerText: '14', isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: '9', isCorrect: true },
        { answerText: '11', isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: '20', isCorrect: false },
      ],
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {questions.map((question) => {
        let answer = question.answerOptions.find((i) => i.isCorrect);
        if (!answer) {
          console.log('Ooops, no way');
        }
        return (
          <p>
            The correct answer for "{question.questionText}" is <b>{answer.answerText}</b>
          </p>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```